# UIPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect problem

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to present a UIPopoverController when a UIButton is clicked. Here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)showColumnChooser:(id)sender {

    ColumnChooserTVC *vc = [[ColumnChooserTVC alloc] init];

    [vc setSelections:allColumns];
    [vc setDelegate:self];
    UIPopoverController *pc = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:vc];


    [pc presentPopoverFromRect:[sender frame] inView:self.view 
      permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                      animated:YES];
    [vc release];
}
```

With the arrow direction as "Any", it completely obscures the button, here's what it looks like:
[image]

If I make the direction "Right", it's a little better but still there's some room between the popover and the button and it doesn't seem right. 
[image]
I don't want to do some "tricks" or "hacks" and use a CGRect on a trial/error basis, I want to know what's the proper way of doing this? Thanks.

Here's the button in interface builder as requested by Neckto:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you are asking for. Can you give more details, please. You want popover arrow to point to another place?

Comment: Well, I want the arrow to point directly  to the button. In this case, do you see the "bars/lines" icon? That what I want the popover arrow to point to. In first example, it completely obscures the icon/button, in second example, it's a bit better but it doesn't point to the button, but a little up and to the left. Hope it's cleat now. thanks.

Comment: Then the problem is in `[sender frame]`. It is too large, probably. How do you create that button?

Comment: It's from interface builder. I simply hooked it up to the IBAction

Comment: Select that button in IB, make screenshot and show it to us. I want to see the frame of this button

Comment: I have updated my question with screenshot of the button.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I think you are mixing coordinate systems. At each level in your view-hiearchy, the origin is moved. So the location of `[sender frame]` in `self.view` is not where the button is located.

Try:

```
[pc presentPopoverFromRect:[sender bounds]
                    inView:sender
  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                  animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

And Swift, Swift, Swift of course!

```
pc.presentPopoverFromRect(sender.bounds, inView: sender, 
permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
```